# Why do file URLs start with 3 slashes?

Tags: browser, filesystems, url

HTTP starts with two slashes. E.g. `http://example.com`.

Same goes for FTP. E.g. `ftp://example.com`.

However, file "URLs" start with three slashes. E.g. Reading a pdf file using chrome, the URL would be `file:///D:/Desktop/Book.pdf`.

**Why** do file URLs use three slashes?

Comment: Opera for Windows expands it to `file://localhost/D:/Desktop/` automatically.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/22772897/632951

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the file schema is in the form "file://<host>/<path>". Though most browsers won't have a problem with only two slashes, and rightfully so.

All things being equal, the triple slash and "localhost" keyword only exist to ensure conformance with valid URI/URL syntax. In the context of the file schema, the host is meaningless since it loads directly from a filesystem without any explicit transfer protocol or server document path. Because it's not HTTP, it can't load from a standard web server where in theory you could have multiple local virtual hosts set up. And it can't load from a standard network volume that's technically another "host", since the browser just uses the volume name like "file:///volumes/foo". Finally, trying things like "file://example.com/some/file" doesn't work. There's probably some reason for supporting an external host, but I can't think of any.

The IETF is currently drafting changes to remove the triple-slash requirement, though the draft also adds a few oddball possibilities like `file:c|/path` and even `file://///host.example.com/path`.

> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-file-scheme-03
>
> "3. This specification neither defines nor forbids a mechanism for accessing non-local files."

Comment: The draft has become [RFC 8089](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8089) in 2017, which still includes your quotation.

Answer (score 285):

The complete syntax is `file://host/path`.

If the host is `localhost`, it can be omitted, resulting in `file:///path`.

See [RFC 1738 – Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> A file URL takes the form:
>
> ```
> file://<host>/<path>
> ```
>
> […]
>
> As a special case, `<host>` can be the string "localhost" or the empty
>      string; this is interpreted as 'the machine from which the URL is
>      being interpreted'.

Comment: Cool, I'd didn't expect the answer to this question a RFC standard!

Comment: @Pacerier Almost *anything* that has to do with the internet can be explained by an RFC (note that they're not necessarily "standards" but may be adopted as such).

Comment: @slhck thx for the info =) Btw I was wondering about this for quite some time but what's with the image @ http://qweop.com/x3 ?

Comment: Perhaps someone should write a blog post about this, explaining how this stuff works in more detail?

Comment: That's quite a popular answer for someone only 15 days into their SU career. Well done Dennis and welcome aboard.

Comment: Note that Tim Berners Lee has apologized for those 2 slashes that are in every URL:  http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/8306631.stm

Comment: Can I omit the `localhost` from other protocols too or does it work only for `file://`?

Comment: Note that Firefox doesn't really follow this standard ` file://test/C:\ ` will behave the same as ` file:///C:\ ` and ` http:///test ` will give an invalid URL error

Comment: Gotta love the RFCs. I don't see why TBL needs to apologize for two slashes. I think they are pretty cool.

Comment: Is it actually possible to use hostnames other than localhost? Is it equivalent to accessing another host on the local network? In what situation has people ever used hosts other than localhost?

Comment: What about the file( /Users/john/filename.crt ) located on local mac OS, would it be `file:///Users/john/filename.crt` ??

Comment: The cited RFC 1738 (from 1994!) has been superseded by [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) (from 2005). The latter only marginally mentions file URIs, which have now been outsourced to [RFC 8089](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8089) (2017). Especially, `file:/path/to/file` is also a valid file URI ([as claimed in appendix A](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8089#appendix-A)).

Comment: @CMCDragonkai did you get your comment's answer ? if yes then please explain to me ?

Answer (score 33):

Dennis has explained the 3rd slash, needed to separate the `host` from the `path`, but the other two are much more interesting...

It turns out they were a useless and somewhat arbitrary addition to the URL syntax. Tim Berners-Lee, inventor of the World Wide Web and author of many of its standards (including [the RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) that Dennis linked to), lamented his usage of the 'double slash' in an interview back in 2009.

> The double slash, though a programming convention at the time, turned out to not be really necessary, Mr. Berners-Lee explained. Look at all the paper and trees, he said, that could have been saved if people had not had to write or type out those slashes on paper over the years — not to mention the human labor and time spent typing those two keystrokes countless millions of times in browser address boxes.

http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/10/12/the-webs-inventor-regrets-one-small-thing/

So, save for a minor (and uncharacteristic) lapse in foresight some 18 years ago, your file URL could just have easily been `file:/D:/Desktop/Book.pdf`, rather than `file:///D:/Desktop/Book.pdf`.

There is, to answer your question, no good reason why URLs have 3 slashes.

---

**Update:** As @ComFreek points out in the comments, as of 2017, the `file:/D:/...` example above is now valid! This is thanks to [RFC 8089](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8089#appendix-A), which specifically calls out this fix from the previous standard...

> According to the definition in [RFC1738], a file URL always started
> with the token "file://", followed by an (optionally blank) host name
> and a "/".  The syntax given in Section 2 makes the entire authority
> component, including the double slashes "//", optional.

What a time to be alive.

Comment: TimBL also elaborates on this in his [FAQ](http://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/FAQ.html#etc)

Comment: Not to mention that 2 bytes could be saved by just using `http:example.com` instead of `http://example.com` It may not seem like a lot, but they add up. Google receives _millions_ of searches a day. How many links are on a page? At least 20. That means for a million searches, if the slashes weren't needed, 20 MB of bandwidth could have been saved.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Did you know you can leave out the protocol part too? So `http://example.com` could be linked to as `//example.com` in a document transmitted over http. It's called a [protocol relative url](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/04/18/protocol-relative-urls/), all browsers support them.

Comment: I am well aware of those, but I personally only use them in CSS. When writing HTML, I use the protocol also. No real reason really. Except maybe because when HTML5+CSS3 first became "big" a few years ago, almost all the sites I looked at were like that.

Comment: @Molomby, He is talking about all the bytes wasted when people don't do relative protocol urls. Which is like >99% of population.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, So you are recommending `h:example.com` instead of `http:example.com`?

Comment: @Pacerier while that would save even more bytes, I wouldn't have recommended that. A single `h` is not clear on what it means unlike `http` (which is clear). Also, take `ftp` and `file` for example. If we use your idea of using the first letter of the acronym only, they'd both be `f`. Sure, the stuff after the protocol would remove the ambiguity (is it a file path of web path), but that would be needlessly complex

Comment: Contrary to what your answer might suggest, `file:/D:/Desktop/Book.pdf` is a valid file URI as per [RFC 8089](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8089#section-2) (from 2017), which superseded [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) (1994) in file URI aspects.